# Sparql Query on GeoNames Ontology using Nearby

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege, geonames

I'm  trying several queries on the site : [http://geosparql.org/](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html)

I'm very interested in trying the clause : NEARBY, for example this query using NEARBY in this way:

```
PREFIX spatial:<http://jena.apache.org/spatial#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX geo:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX gn:<http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>

Select * 
WHERE{
?object spatial:nearby(40.74 -73.989 1 'mi').
?object rdfs:label ?label
}LIMIT 10
```

When i execute the query on site [http://geosparql.org/](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html) all is ok but now i desire download the GeoNames Ontology and execute it on my PC.

here i have found the ontology for download: http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html

He tells me that The Ontology for GeoNames is available in OWL :

http://www.geonames.org/ontology/ontology_v3.1.rd

I download it but when i open ontology with software Protegè or with Sparql Droid on my smarphone Android and execute same query I get no data maybe the ontology is empty?

How do I fill the ontology, in order to run this query?

Thank you very much to those who will help me.

Comment: Ok but how can import the individual for execute and obtain data for this query or similar ?

Answer (score 2):

The ontology is the *vocabulary* (i.e., definition of classes, properties, etc.) An ontology doesn't necessarily include the individuals (e.g., the places, locations, etc.) that you might be interested in.  In this case, I think you've downloaded the ontology, which is relatively small, but you're probably interested in the data dumps that that page describes later.  I think the fourth option is the one that you want:

> #### [Entry Points into the GeoNames Semantic Web](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html)
>
> There are several ways how you can enter the GeoNames Semantic Web :
>
> - …
> - [RDF dump](http://download.geonames.org/all-geonames-rdf.zip) with 10113356 features and about 150 mio rdf triples (2015 04 21). The dump has one rdf document per toponym on every line of the
>     file. Note: The file is pretty large. Make sure the tool you use to
>     uncompress is able to deal with the size and does not stop after 2GB,
>     an issue that happens with some old (windows) tool versions.

Comment: ok but it open a big file .txt about 12GB insteand i have found at this link [link](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/) other txt example the IT.zip file but my problem is how Import .txt individual in ontology with Protegè?

Comment: @javierZanetti Check the readme in that zip file, though.  That's not RDF content;  it's raw data from the database dumps.  You can't load that into Protege directly.

Answer (score 2):

Open the web page [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html) then Clic on the given OWl URI [Geonames Ontology](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/ontology_v3.1.rdf) the geonames onto is then downloaded. open protégé then menu File> Open and import the owl document the ontology concepts is then added to protégé; use it to add your own instanc